# unrecognized selector sent to instance exception in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, nsstring

I have a requirement to check whether a String contains a particular string or not.For that purpose i am using a function of NSString class called c**containsstring**. This function works fine in ios8 without throwing any kind of exception but in case of ios7 it is throwing an exception called

```
 unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have used try & catch block to prevent the exception but may i know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please put code snippet which you have used so you can get correct solution?

Comment: please paste the code to solve your problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410420/nsstring-containsstring-crashes

Comment: NSString *Test=arr_sub[0];   
                          
  if([Test containsString:@"::"])
  {
     NSlog(@"charecter found");
   }

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check in framework header.
[image]

```
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)aString NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
```

This method of containsString only exist after iOS 8 so its obvious that it will throw error in iOS7....

Please use below method for ios7  and you can use above method for ios8:

```
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location != NSNotFound)
{
  NSLog(@"charecter found");
}
```

May be this can solve your issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. containsString function added in iOS 8. So we can't use it in iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

Check if String retrieved from array is not `nil`. It will solve your problem.

Use following code it might resolve your issue.

```
NSString *Test=arr_sub[0];
if(Test!=nil && [Test containsString:@"::"])
{
    NSlog(@"charecter found");
}
```

Let me know if you face any other isssue.

Comment: `NSString *strn = @"my vals";
    
    if ([strn containsString:@"va"]) {
        NSLog(@"GOT IT RE...");
    }`  This thing works in ios8 but throws exception in iOS7.

Comment: I think this function is added in ios8 & does not work in ios7 that is why it is throwing an exception. i have checked on both ios8 & ios7