# Restrict app to devices with touch id

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532649/how-do-i-restrict-my-app-for-only-iphone-6-and-6-plus), it's not possible to restrict supported device to specific device models but I also read that it's possible to restrict it when your device is using a specific hardware via `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` but I didn't see any key that pertains to devices with touch ID.

My question is, is there an app review safe way to restrict my app only to devices with touch ID? I may have overlooked some keys in the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`.

Just to add, I already know how to restrict it via code but the problem is it might get rejected in the app review based on my research so my only hope is in the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` maybe some combination of the existing keys that may lead to devices with touch id.

Reason:
Fingerprint scanning is one of the primary security feature of the app.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to restrict the app to touch ID devices only.

Comment: `florieger's` comments: Can you please clarify what you want to achieve? Based on the first part of your question, I assume that you want to restrict your app to certain devices. What's the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) as well. There is no key to restrict the app to devices with Touch ID.

This might be a [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Whilst the first part of you answer is actually an answer which I don't have any issues with the second part is asking for additional information these are comments not answers. Please use the comments section under the question if you'd like to ask for additional information. As such I have edited your answer to removed the questions from your answer.

Comment: @Popeye, thanks for the hint. I wanted to do that in the first place, but my rep was two low to add a comment. Since I had already looked through the capabilities list, I wanted to share it with the author.

Comment: I have added your comments to the questions for you and +1 your answer as I believe you are correct in what you are saying.